# How to transfer page_number to urls.py

Tags: python, django

I want transfer *page_number* to url with *name='onePart'* from part_list.html. In my code *page_number=1*, but I want change it to current page of paginator depends on page. How I can do this?

P.S. sorry for my english:)

**views.py**:

```
    def PartyNumView(request, page_number = 1):
        all_parties = Part.objects.all()
        current_page = Paginator(all_parties, 1)
        try:
            context = current_page.page(page_number)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            context = current_page.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            context = current_page.page(current_page.num_pages)

        return render_to_response('part_list.html', {'PartyNum': context})

    def forOne(request, pk):
        onePart = get_object_or_404(Part, pk=pk)
        return render_to_response('SinglePart.html', {'onePart': onePart})
**urls.py:**
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^parties/(\d+)/$', PartyNumView),
    url(r'^parties', PartyNumView),
    url(r'parties/(?P<page_number>[\d]+)/(?P<pk>[\d]+)$', forOne, name='onePart'),
    url(r'^main/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='main.html')),       #static html
    url(r'^measures/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='IcDesc.html')),       #static html
]
```

A little bit of HTML code **part_list.html:**

```
{% for object in PartyNum %}

    <tr>
      <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'onePart' pk=object.pk  page_number=1%}"> {{ object.Party_number }}</a></td>
      <td>{{ object.Film }}</td>
      <td>{{ object.Thick }}</td>
      <td>{{ object.Critical_temperature }}</td>
      <td>{{ object.R_s }}</td>

  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>

</table>
        </table>

<div class="row" style="margin:auto">
        <div class="large-3 large-offset-5 columns">
            <ul class="pagination">
                {% if PartyNum.has_previous %}
                    <li class="arrow"><a href="/parties/{{ PartyNum.previous_page_number }}/">&laquo;</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="arrow disabled"><a href="">&laquo;</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% for page in PartyNum.paginator.page_range %}
                    {% if page == PartyNum.number %}
                        <li class="current"><a href="/parties/{{ page }}/">{{ page }}</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="/parties/{{ page }}/">{{ page }}</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if PartyNum.has_next %}
                    <li class="arrow"><a href="/parties/{{ PartyNum.next_page_number }}/">&raquo;</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="arrow disabled"><a href="">&raquo;</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm begginer in django. If you help me, I will be grateful

Comment: And ? What's the problem with your code ? Are we supposed to guess ???

Comment: I want to send to urls.py number of page of each object  in Party number.  And I don't know how to realize it

Comment: I repeat: __what's the problem with your code ?__ (you already told us what you wanted to do - it's even your question's title - so no need to repeat it).

Comment: There are not problem in my code.

Comment: Excuse me but I must be missing womething here... If your code works (does what you want it to do), why do you post here ?

Comment: :)  My code works, but I want to change it so that it works differently. And I ask how to realize what I want. I think our misunderstanding arose because of my poor knowledge of English

Answer (score 0):

> Pagination with Function-Based Views

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(user_list, 10)
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'core/user_list.html', { 'users': users })
```

user_list.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

{% if users.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if users.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in users.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if users.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if users.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```